# Why does my printed tikz image have a black background?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, printing

In my Latex document I have a lot of TikZ figures generated by `\addplot3[surf, shader = interp,...]`. In my PDF this figures look quite good. However, if I print the PDF, there is a black background. The black backround dissapears if I use the option `\addplot3[surf, shader = flat corner,...]`. Here a scanned example:

[image]

Update:

I found some strange behaviour. I tried to create the plot with different settings. If I use:
 `\addplot3[%
surf,
shader=faceted interp, faceted color=black,`
the printed figure is equal to the pdf. However, this needs a lot of memory as discussed here: 
[TikZ: How to get a smooth surface plot without significant increasing needed memory](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/349274/tikz-how-to-get-a-smooth-surface-plot-without-significant-increasing-needed-mem)

Here a scanned page of the printed figures with differnet settings:

[image]

And the Code used to generate the second figure:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}           
\newlength\figureheight 
\newlength\figurewidth 



\begin{document}

\setlength\figureheight{5cm}
\setlength\figurewidth{5cm}


\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
width=0.951\figurewidth,
height=\figureheight,
at={(0\figurewidth,0\figureheight)},
scale only axis,
xmin=0,
xmax=2,
tick align=outside,
xlabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
xlabel={x},
ymin=0,
ymax=2,
ylabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
ylabel={y},
zmin=0.115,
zmax=0.135,
zlabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
zlabel={z},
view={83.7}{48},
axis background/.style={fill=white},
axis x line*=bottom,
axis y line*=left,
axis z line*=left,
xmajorgrids,
ymajorgrids,
zmajorgrids
]

\addplot3[%
surf,
shader=interp, colormap={mymap}{[1pt] rgb(0pt)=(0.2081,0.1663,0.5292); rgb(1pt)=(0.211624,0.189781,0.577676); rgb(2pt)=(0.212252,0.213771,0.626971); rgb(3pt)=(0.2081,0.2386,0.677086); rgb(4pt)=(0.195905,0.264457,0.7279); rgb(5pt)=(0.170729,0.291938,0.779248); rgb(6pt)=(0.125271,0.324243,0.830271); rgb(7pt)=(0.0591333,0.359833,0.868333); rgb(8pt)=(0.0116952,0.38751,0.881957); rgb(9pt)=(0.00595714,0.408614,0.882843); rgb(10pt)=(0.0165143,0.4266,0.878633); rgb(11pt)=(0.0328524,0.443043,0.871957); rgb(12pt)=(0.0498143,0.458571,0.864057); rgb(13pt)=(0.0629333,0.47369,0.855438); rgb(14pt)=(0.0722667,0.488667,0.8467); rgb(15pt)=(0.0779429,0.503986,0.838371); rgb(16pt)=(0.0793476,0.520024,0.831181); rgb(17pt)=(0.0749429,0.537543,0.826271); rgb(18pt)=(0.0640571,0.556986,0.823957); rgb(19pt)=(0.0487714,0.577224,0.822829); rgb(20pt)=(0.0343429,0.596581,0.819852); rgb(21pt)=(0.0265,0.6137,0.8135); rgb(22pt)=(0.0238905,0.628662,0.803762); rgb(23pt)=(0.0230905,0.641786,0.791267); rgb(24pt)=(0.0227714,0.653486,0.776757); rgb(25pt)=(0.0266619,0.664195,0.760719); rgb(26pt)=(0.0383714,0.674271,0.743552); rgb(27pt)=(0.0589714,0.683757,0.725386); rgb(28pt)=(0.0843,0.692833,0.706167); rgb(29pt)=(0.113295,0.7015,0.685857); rgb(30pt)=(0.145271,0.709757,0.664629); rgb(31pt)=(0.180133,0.717657,0.642433); rgb(32pt)=(0.217829,0.725043,0.619262); rgb(33pt)=(0.258643,0.731714,0.595429); rgb(34pt)=(0.302171,0.737605,0.571186); rgb(35pt)=(0.348167,0.742433,0.547267); rgb(36pt)=(0.395257,0.7459,0.524443); rgb(37pt)=(0.44201,0.748081,0.503314); rgb(38pt)=(0.487124,0.749062,0.483976); rgb(39pt)=(0.530029,0.749114,0.466114); rgb(40pt)=(0.570857,0.748519,0.44939); rgb(41pt)=(0.609852,0.747314,0.433686); rgb(42pt)=(0.6473,0.7456,0.4188); rgb(43pt)=(0.683419,0.743476,0.404433); rgb(44pt)=(0.71841,0.741133,0.390476); rgb(45pt)=(0.752486,0.7384,0.376814); rgb(46pt)=(0.785843,0.735567,0.363271); rgb(47pt)=(0.818505,0.732733,0.34979); rgb(48pt)=(0.850657,0.7299,0.336029); rgb(49pt)=(0.882433,0.727433,0.3217); rgb(50pt)=(0.913933,0.725786,0.306276); rgb(51pt)=(0.944957,0.726114,0.288643); rgb(52pt)=(0.973895,0.731395,0.266648); rgb(53pt)=(0.993771,0.745457,0.240348); rgb(54pt)=(0.999043,0.765314,0.216414); rgb(55pt)=(0.995533,0.786057,0.196652); rgb(56pt)=(0.988,0.8066,0.179367); rgb(57pt)=(0.978857,0.827143,0.163314); rgb(58pt)=(0.9697,0.848138,0.147452); rgb(59pt)=(0.962586,0.870514,0.1309); rgb(60pt)=(0.958871,0.8949,0.113243); rgb(61pt)=(0.959824,0.921833,0.0948381); rgb(62pt)=(0.9661,0.951443,0.0755333); rgb(63pt)=(0.9763,0.9831,0.0538)}, mesh/rows=20]
table[row sep=crcr] {%
    %
    x   y   z   c\\
    0.1 0.1 0.118005627299026   0.118005627299026\\
    0.1 0.2 0.117999121884957   0.117999121884957\\
    0.1 0.3 0.117933663867318   0.117933663867318\\
    0.1 0.4 0.117922384509641   0.117922384509641\\
    0.1 0.5 0.117969098160825   0.117969098160825\\
    0.1 0.6 0.118096816191612   0.118096816191612\\
    0.1 0.7 0.118288442403696   0.118288442403696\\
    0.1 0.8 0.118606412505066   0.118606412505066\\
    0.1 0.9 0.119045859410718   0.119045859410718\\
    0.1 1   0.119524958632958   0.119524958632958\\
    0.1 1.1 0.120122916884566   0.120122916884566\\
    0.1 1.2 0.120802860126124   0.120802860126124\\
    0.1 1.3 0.12153577921035    0.12153577921035\\
    0.1 1.4 0.122428572628211   0.122428572628211\\
    0.1 1.5 0.123260359844326   0.123260359844326\\
    0.1 1.6 0.123994228140075   0.123994228140075\\
    0.1 1.7 0.124741095452459   0.124741095452459\\
    0.1 1.8 0.125528154248117   0.125528154248117\\
    0.1 1.9 0.12633079445887    0.12633079445887\\
    0.1 2   0.127111827075881   0.127111827075881\\
    0.2 0.1 0.118006152190351   0.118006152190351\\
    0.2 0.2 0.117999613082177   0.117999613082177\\
    0.2 0.3 0.117933901296617   0.117933901296617\\
    0.2 0.4 0.117921985364741   0.117921985364741\\
    0.2 0.5 0.117968270188668   0.117968270188668\\
    0.2 0.6 0.118096470454609   0.118096470454609\\
    0.2 0.7 0.11828840597347    0.11828840597347\\
    0.2 0.8 0.1186063803985 0.1186063803985\\
    0.2 0.9 0.119045804971326   0.119045804971326\\
    0.2 1   0.119524872503438   0.119524872503438\\
    0.2 1.1 0.120122732652741   0.120122732652741\\
    0.2 1.2 0.120802712740583   0.120802712740583\\
    0.2 1.3 0.121535620839741   0.121535620839741\\
    0.2 1.4 0.122428369799725   0.122428369799725\\
    0.2 1.5 0.123260161799967   0.123260161799967\\
    0.2 1.6 0.12399404451168    0.12399404451168\\
    0.2 1.7 0.124740921984977   0.124740921984977\\
    0.2 1.8 0.125528017450978   0.125528017450978\\
    0.2 1.9 0.126330706959058   0.126330706959058\\
    0.2 2   0.127111775237731   0.127111775237731\\
    0.3 0.1 0.118059173704593   0.118059173704593\\
    0.3 0.2 0.118052126635811   0.118052126635811\\
    0.3 0.3 0.117988204629036   0.117988204629036\\
    0.3 0.4 0.117976035263109   0.117976035263109\\
    0.3 0.5 0.118025235995228   0.118025235995228\\
    0.3 0.6 0.118149286340685   0.118149286340685\\
    0.3 0.7 0.118332275568628   0.118332275568628\\
    0.3 0.8 0.118641395040554   0.118641395040554\\
    0.3 0.9 0.119084215768013   0.119084215768013\\
    0.3 1   0.119554557198401   0.119554557198401\\
    0.3 1.1 0.120158003518724   0.120158003518724\\
    0.3 1.2 0.120834744888836   0.120834744888836\\
    0.3 1.3 0.121599148806447   0.121599148806447\\
    0.3 1.4 0.122454933146085   0.122454933146085\\
    0.3 1.5 0.123283331151076   0.123283331151076\\
    0.3 1.6 0.124047725761854   0.124047725761854\\
    0.3 1.7 0.124767681472039   0.124767681472039\\
    0.3 1.8 0.125552128990572   0.125552128990572\\
    0.3 1.9 0.126350951286901   0.126350951286901\\
    0.3 2   0.127132747622288   0.127132747622288\\
    0.4 0.1 0.118150388125295   0.118150388125295\\
    0.4 0.2 0.118145110629863   0.118145110629863\\
    0.4 0.3 0.118079798574259   0.118079798574259\\
    0.4 0.4 0.118056230845774   0.118056230845774\\
    0.4 0.5 0.118102889333077   0.118102889333077\\
    0.4 0.6 0.118211305211416   0.118211305211416\\
    0.4 0.7 0.118410627041924   0.118410627041924\\
    0.4 0.8 0.118709876297747   0.118709876297747\\
    0.4 0.9 0.119133388710601   0.119133388710601\\
    0.4 1   0.119596599762159   0.119596599762159\\
    0.4 1.1 0.120193081902855   0.120193081902855\\
    0.4 1.2 0.120876704367874   0.120876704367874\\
    0.4 1.3 0.121605646844449   0.121605646844449\\
    0.4 1.4 0.122450066859226   0.122450066859226\\
    0.4 1.5 0.123256971519828   0.123256971519828\\
    0.4 1.6 0.124038604221032   0.124038604221032\\
    0.4 1.7 0.124749984125078   0.124749984125078\\
    0.4 1.8 0.125595503155953   0.125595503155953\\
    0.4 1.9 0.126387651384292   0.126387651384292\\
    0.4 2   0.12714929240436    0.12714929240436\\
    0.5 0.1 0.118382481992347   0.118382481992347\\
    0.5 0.2 0.118380111732936   0.118380111732936\\
    0.5 0.3 0.118316868175601   0.118316868175601\\
    0.5 0.4 0.118290621690353   0.118290621690353\\
    0.5 0.5 0.118337155685042   0.118337155685042\\
    0.5 0.6 0.118443935463119   0.118443935463119\\
    0.5 0.7 0.118629504273017   0.118629504273017\\
    0.5 0.8 0.118895845309552   0.118895845309552\\
    0.5 0.9 0.11931050651422    0.11931050651422\\
    0.5 1   0.119747861343694   0.119747861343694\\
    0.5 1.1 0.120289381775964   0.120289381775964\\
    0.5 1.2 0.121005022281414   0.121005022281414\\
    0.5 1.3 0.121716089346938   0.121716089346938\\
    0.5 1.4 0.122492071571699   0.122492071571699\\
    0.5 1.5 0.123310066002432   0.123310066002432\\
    0.5 1.6 0.124033722403259   0.124033722403259\\
    0.5 1.7 0.124741537219495   0.124741537219495\\
    0.5 1.8 0.125572381464623   0.125572381464623\\
    0.5 1.9 0.12635606253823    0.12635606253823\\
    0.5 2   0.127133692149428   0.127133692149428\\
    0.6 0.1 0.118776707562668   0.118776707562668\\
    0.6 0.2 0.118773952569404   0.118773952569404\\
    0.6 0.3 0.118710065841954   0.118710065841954\\
    0.6 0.4 0.118678572588141   0.118678572588141\\
    0.6 0.5 0.11871499751629    0.11871499751629\\
    0.6 0.6 0.118804403473125   0.118804403473125\\
    0.6 0.7 0.118958054406058   0.118958054406058\\
    0.6 0.8 0.119226311230559   0.119226311230559\\
    0.6 0.9 0.119617535402065   0.119617535402065\\
    0.6 1   0.120028483300873   0.120028483300873\\
    0.6 1.1 0.120576933626883   0.120576933626883\\
    0.6 1.2 0.121207265180294   0.121207265180294\\
    0.6 1.3 0.121895550669919   0.121895550669919\\
    0.6 1.4 0.12264141182305    0.12264141182305\\
    0.6 1.5 0.123367575922296   0.123367575922296\\
    0.6 1.6 0.124152739594899   0.124152739594899\\
    0.6 1.7 0.124864511303199   0.124864511303199\\
    0.6 1.8 0.125616133844198   0.125616133844198\\
    0.6 1.9 0.126392779907781   0.126392779907781\\
    0.6 2   0.127148358100439   0.127148358100439\\
    0.7 0.1 0.119219821840289   0.119219821840289\\
    0.7 0.2 0.119219224376238   0.119219224376238\\
    0.7 0.3 0.119171518698709   0.119171518698709\\
    0.7 0.4 0.119137447636073   0.119137447636073\\
    0.7 0.5 0.119154604618404   0.119154604618404\\
    0.7 0.6 0.119256483180003   0.119256483180003\\
    0.7 0.7 0.119403675988204   0.119403675988204\\
    0.7 0.8 0.119643506699714   0.119643506699714\\
    0.7 0.9 0.120012662336651   0.120012662336651\\
    0.7 1   0.120438753919146   0.120438753919146\\
    0.7 1.1 0.120892613272804   0.120892613272804\\
    0.7 1.2 0.121502318581009   0.121502318581009\\
    0.7 1.3 0.122120524290279   0.122120524290279\\
    0.7 1.4 0.122853317269065   0.122853317269065\\
    0.7 1.5 0.123552634895159   0.123552634895159\\
    0.7 1.6 0.124259425997432   0.124259425997432\\
    0.7 1.7 0.125023704073756   0.125023704073756\\
    0.7 1.8 0.125761075439367   0.125761075439367\\
    0.7 1.9 0.126516228118373   0.126516228118373\\
    0.7 2   0.127245043447263   0.127245043447263\\
    0.8 0.1 0.119778415640742   0.119778415640742\\
    0.8 0.2 0.11977794346283    0.11977794346283\\
    0.8 0.3 0.119734049327663   0.119734049327663\\
    0.8 0.4 0.119695910760651   0.119695910760651\\
    0.8 0.5 0.119686936018035   0.119686936018035\\
    0.8 0.6 0.119769751477758   0.119769751477758\\
    0.8 0.7 0.119908312863211   0.119908312863211\\
    0.8 0.8 0.120184632614894   0.120184632614894\\
    0.8 0.9 0.120521845742997   0.120521845742997\\
    0.8 1   0.120903323369105   0.120903323369105\\
    0.8 1.1 0.121354836840712   0.121354836840712\\
    0.8 1.2 0.121925198534988   0.121925198534988\\
    0.8 1.3 0.122502693343412   0.122502693343412\\
    0.8 1.4 0.123140330268898   0.123140330268898\\
    0.8 1.5 0.123807236984425   0.123807236984425\\
    0.8 1.6 0.124480560440091   0.124480560440091\\
    0.8 1.7 0.125154787241569   0.125154787241569\\
    0.8 1.8 0.125890173747846   0.125890173747846\\
    0.8 1.9 0.126671002579633   0.126671002579633\\
    0.8 2   0.127409085899877   0.127409085899877\\
    0.9 0.1 0.12040824781683    0.12040824781683\\
    0.9 0.2 0.120407845428353   0.120407845428353\\
    0.9 0.3 0.120374866453464   0.120374866453464\\
    0.9 0.4 0.120326635575564   0.120326635575564\\
    0.9 0.5 0.120287832821293   0.120287832821293\\
    0.9 0.6 0.120354172324611   0.120354172324611\\
    0.9 0.7 0.120482714254229   0.120482714254229\\
    0.9 0.8 0.120685869627196   0.120685869627196\\
    0.9 0.9 0.12100490629046    0.12100490629046\\
    0.9 1   0.121371619909334   0.121371619909334\\
    0.9 1.1 0.12183775684496    0.12183775684496\\
    0.9 1.2 0.122374839401461   0.122374839401461\\
    0.9 1.3 0.122881201705506   0.122881201705506\\
    0.9 1.4 0.123529707962394   0.123529707962394\\
    0.9 1.5 0.124130125135898   0.124130125135898\\
    0.9 1.6 0.124798191299781   0.124798191299781\\
    0.9 1.7 0.125464438991712   0.125464438991712\\
    0.9 1.8 0.126117055979003   0.126117055979003\\
    0.9 1.9 0.126895485866536   0.126895485866536\\
    0.9 2   0.127587442848818   0.127587442848818\\
    1   0.1 0.121075489846363   0.121075489846363\\
    1   0.2 0.12107507443136    0.12107507443136\\
    1   0.3 0.121043653152958   0.121043653152958\\
    1   0.4 0.12097322552311    0.12097322552311\\
    1   0.5 0.120958092958134   0.120958092958134\\
    1   0.6 0.121016061653674   0.121016061653674\\
    1   0.7 0.121119541988488   0.121119541988488\\
    1   0.8 0.121300164787971   0.121300164787971\\
    1   0.9 0.121568553370437   0.121568553370437\\
    1   1   0.12192834548266    0.12192834548266\\
    1   1.1 0.122337227096322   0.122337227096322\\
    1   1.2 0.122823280284365   0.122823280284365\\
    1   1.3 0.123380981008948   0.123380981008948\\
    1   1.4 0.124017314245699   0.124017314245699\\
    1   1.5 0.124593656666783   0.124593656666783\\
    1   1.6 0.125219259349737   0.125219259349737\\
    1   1.7 0.125788847611408   0.125788847611408\\
    1   1.8 0.126408901145818   0.126408901145818\\
    1   1.9 0.127112872554427   0.127112872554427\\
    1   2   0.127838281120025   0.127838281120025\\
    1.1 0.1 0.121735052932198   0.121735052932198\\
    1.1 0.2 0.121734615425692   0.121734615425692\\
    1.1 0.3 0.121708013125027   0.121708013125027\\
    1.1 0.4 0.121670157360353   0.121670157360353\\
    1.1 0.5 0.121638999477061   0.121638999477061\\
    1.1 0.6 0.121695527421172   0.121695527421172\\
    1.1 0.7 0.121773039122266   0.121773039122266\\
    1.1 0.8 0.121939311208994   0.121939311208994\\
    1.1 0.9 0.122180901166744   0.122180901166744\\
    1.1 1   0.122472788603083   0.122472788603083\\
    1.1 1.1 0.122862718221309   0.122862718221309\\
    1.1 1.2 0.123310205629437   0.123310205629437\\
    1.1 1.3 0.123833120887177   0.123833120887177\\
    1.1 1.4 0.12443964072744    0.12443964072744\\
    1.1 1.5 0.12499604898393    0.12499604898393\\
    1.1 1.6 0.125586508966884   0.125586508966884\\
    1.1 1.7 0.126091132615325   0.126091132615325\\
    1.1 1.8 0.126721304305939   0.126721304305939\\
    1.1 1.9 0.127381177921913   0.127381177921913\\
    1.1 2   0.128021313943143   0.128021313943143\\
    1.2 0.1 0.12239463639037    0.12239463639037\\
    1.2 0.2 0.122394264323839   0.122394264323839\\
    1.2 0.3 0.122369651503443   0.122369651503443\\
    1.2 0.4 0.122321941969542   0.122321941969542\\
    1.2 0.5 0.122285903757519   0.122285903757519\\
    1.2 0.6 0.12229363591798    0.12229363591798\\
    1.2 0.7 0.122382812852044   0.122382812852044\\
    1.2 0.8 0.122534737721215   0.122534737721215\\
    1.2 0.9 0.122778505651675   0.122778505651675\\
    1.2 1   0.123043465298739   0.123043465298739\\
    1.2 1.1 0.123350573445566   0.123350573445566\\
    1.2 1.2 0.123771189341825   0.123771189341825\\
    1.2 1.3 0.124281894166975   0.124281894166975\\
    1.2 1.4 0.124829912362131   0.124829912362131\\
    1.2 1.5 0.125389175926077   0.125389175926077\\
    1.2 1.6 0.125940235137119   0.125940235137119\\
    1.2 1.7 0.126427656561449   0.126427656561449\\
    1.2 1.8 0.127057145846348   0.127057145846348\\
    1.2 1.9 0.127705426776822   0.127705426776822\\
    1.2 2   0.128313196669677   0.128313196669677\\
    1.3 0.1 0.123092947847395   0.123092947847395\\
    1.3 0.2 0.123092680279949   0.123092680279949\\
    1.3 0.3 0.123070525186354   0.123070525186354\\
    1.3 0.4 0.123004297726921   0.123004297726921\\
    1.3 0.5 0.122971288954029   0.122971288954029\\
    1.3 0.6 0.122961760300422   0.122961760300422\\
    1.3 0.7 0.123002715289145   0.123002715289145\\
    1.3 0.8 0.123153392765409   0.123153392765409\\
    1.3 0.9 0.123399633401172   0.123399633401172\\
    1.3 1   0.123658740078366   0.123658740078366\\
    1.3 1.1 0.123995871758211   0.123995871758211\\
    1.3 1.2 0.124355588893192   0.124355588893192\\
    1.3 1.3 0.124800619182134   0.124800619182134\\
    1.3 1.4 0.125356637928421   0.125356637928421\\
    1.3 1.5 0.125877847740667   0.125877847740667\\
    1.3 1.6 0.126396522070489   0.126396522070489\\
    1.3 1.7 0.126882611034783   0.126882611034783\\
    1.3 1.8 0.127483753714549   0.127483753714549\\
    1.3 1.9 0.12808883122055    0.12808883122055\\
    1.3 2   0.128705156193341   0.128705156193341\\
    1.4 0.1 0.123731867564251   0.123731867564251\\
    1.4 0.2 0.123731821192949   0.123731821192949\\
    1.4 0.3 0.12370728495287    0.12370728495287\\
    1.4 0.4 0.123653344672294   0.123653344672294\\
    1.4 0.5 0.123614263504023   0.123614263504023\\
    1.4 0.6 0.123609813296242   0.123609813296242\\
    1.4 0.7 0.12366221094787    0.12366221094787\\
    1.4 0.8 0.123810579080478   0.123810579080478\\
    1.4 0.9 0.124020427986294   0.124020427986294\\
    1.4 1   0.124275634632305   0.124275634632305\\
    1.4 1.1 0.124609504566588   0.124609504566588\\
    1.4 1.2 0.124970621336963   0.124970621336963\\
    1.4 1.3 0.125383898410526   0.125383898410526\\
    1.4 1.4 0.125835874404007   0.125835874404007\\
    1.4 1.5 0.126360853746958   0.126360853746958\\
    1.4 1.6 0.126839263981225   0.126839263981225\\
    1.4 1.7 0.12732541241719    0.12732541241719\\
    1.4 1.8 0.12792097249959    0.12792097249959\\
    1.4 1.9 0.12848556709778    0.12848556709778\\
    1.4 2   0.129064519077965   0.129064519077965\\
    1.5 0.1 0.124479459198337   0.124479459198337\\
    1.5 0.2 0.124479459198337   0.124479459198337\\
    1.5 0.3 0.124480380410889   0.124480380410889\\
    1.5 0.4 0.124437186540066   0.124437186540066\\
    1.5 0.5 0.124377593462045   0.124377593462045\\
    1.5 0.6 0.124367691791448   0.124367691791448\\
    1.5 0.7 0.124387012159645   0.124387012159645\\
    1.5 0.8 0.124509974454513   0.124509974454513\\
    1.5 0.9 0.124708851654213   0.124708851654213\\
    1.5 1   0.124951351884298   0.124951351884298\\
    1.5 1.1 0.125266510302688   0.125266510302688\\
    1.5 1.2 0.125587759600307   0.125587759600307\\
    1.5 1.3 0.12598902923353    0.12598902923353\\
    1.5 1.4 0.126476737159527   0.126476737159527\\
    1.5 1.5 0.126947912998139   0.126947912998139\\
    1.5 1.6 0.127414508032903   0.127414508032903\\
    1.5 1.7 0.127862731084182   0.127862731084182\\
    1.5 1.8 0.128434827858334   0.128434827858334\\
    1.5 1.9 0.129006832195505   0.129006832195505\\
    1.5 2   0.129510050167702   0.129510050167702\\
    1.6 0.1 0.125271012139505   0.125271012139505\\
    1.6 0.2 0.125271012139505   0.125271012139505\\
    1.6 0.3 0.125237353259027   0.125237353259027\\
    1.6 0.4 0.125224890728038   0.125224890728038\\
    1.6 0.5 0.125130084822001   0.125130084822001\\
    1.6 0.6 0.125116445396539   0.125116445396539\\
    1.6 0.7 0.125124004317053   0.125124004317053\\
    1.6 0.8 0.12523287014164    0.12523287014164\\
    1.6 0.9 0.125405647710848   0.125405647710848\\
    1.6 1   0.125623520390795   0.125623520390795\\
    1.6 1.1 0.125899829034313   0.125899829034313\\
    1.6 1.2 0.126225187659483   0.126225187659483\\
    1.6 1.3 0.126606797452073   0.126606797452073\\
    1.6 1.4 0.127056034671284   0.127056034671284\\
    1.6 1.5 0.127492417283784   0.127492417283784\\
    1.6 1.6 0.128004975843275   0.128004975843275\\
    1.6 1.7 0.12840331038153    0.12840331038153\\
    1.6 1.8 0.128923831190856   0.128923831190856\\
    1.6 1.9 0.12950689481166    0.12950689481166\\
    1.6 2   0.130025821199583   0.130025821199583\\
    1.7 0.1 0.126016592322869   0.126016592322869\\
    1.7 0.2 0.126016592322869   0.126016592322869\\
    1.7 0.3 0.1260000811504 0.1260000811504\\
    1.7 0.4 0.125945090224377   0.125945090224377\\
    1.7 0.5 0.125872173248937   0.125872173248937\\
    1.7 0.6 0.12583569315606    0.12583569315606\\
    1.7 0.7 0.125845495866653   0.125845495866653\\
    1.7 0.8 0.125938805678399   0.125938805678399\\
    1.7 0.9 0.126083039676938   0.126083039676938\\
    1.7 1   0.126311763368515   0.126311763368515\\
    1.7 1.1 0.126583989948805   0.126583989948805\\
    1.7 1.2 0.126863831151277   0.126863831151277\\
    1.7 1.3 0.127247938851709   0.127247938851709\\
    1.7 1.4 0.127635108318136   0.127635108318136\\
    1.7 1.5 0.128067920995473   0.128067920995473\\
    1.7 1.6 0.12851112177079    0.12851112177079\\
    1.7 1.7 0.128877901623181   0.128877901623181\\
    1.7 1.8 0.129403367701929   0.129403367701929\\
    1.7 1.9 0.129983299500929   0.129983299500929\\
    1.7 2   0.130564018465621   0.130564018465621\\
    1.8 0.1 0.126800636483832   0.126800636483832\\
    1.8 0.2 0.126800636483832   0.126800636483832\\
    1.8 0.3 0.126786239419393   0.126786239419393\\
    1.8 0.4 0.126733587545117   0.126733587545117\\
    1.8 0.5 0.12665227552749    0.12665227552749\\
    1.8 0.6 0.126603721049263   0.126603721049263\\
    1.8 0.7 0.126588498667395   0.126588498667395\\
    1.8 0.8 0.126669539069551   0.126669539069551\\
    1.8 0.9 0.126817221248348   0.126817221248348\\
    1.8 1   0.127011829802431   0.127011829802431\\
    1.8 1.1 0.127234674052242   0.127234674052242\\
    1.8 1.2 0.127573236046792   0.127573236046792\\
    1.8 1.3 0.127917187386404   0.127917187386404\\
    1.8 1.4 0.128304393997696   0.128304393997696\\
    1.8 1.5 0.12868228456872    0.12868228456872\\
    1.8 1.6 0.129085141309258   0.129085141309258\\
    1.8 1.7 0.129451332885391   0.129451332885391\\
    1.8 1.8 0.129983293526991   0.129983293526991\\
    1.8 1.9 0.130556186737648   0.130556186737648\\
    1.8 2   0.131041715017151   0.131041715017151\\
    1.9 0.1 0.127607673735276   0.127607673735276\\
    1.9 0.2 0.127607673735276   0.127607673735276\\
    1.9 0.3 0.127597741042979   0.127597741042979\\
    1.9 0.4 0.127525573647916   0.127525573647916\\
    1.9 0.5 0.127456607772333   0.127456607772333\\
    1.9 0.6 0.127363775149427   0.127363775149427\\
    1.9 0.7 0.127375401009451   0.127375401009451\\
    1.9 0.8 0.127438162918825   0.127438162918825\\
    1.9 0.9 0.127558312942805   0.127558312942805\\
    1.9 1   0.127737545286852   0.127737545286852\\
    1.9 1.1 0.127959470777949   0.127959470777949\\
    1.9 1.2 0.128250737098562   0.128250737098562\\
    1.9 1.3 0.128590241778314   0.128590241778314\\
    1.9 1.4 0.128970311343687   0.128970311343687\\
    1.9 1.5 0.12935601055755    0.12935601055755\\
    1.9 1.6 0.129728195299538   0.129728195299538\\
    1.9 1.7 0.130111797981353   0.130111797981353\\
    1.9 1.8 0.130574715057576   0.130574715057576\\
    1.9 1.9 0.131184702544822   0.131184702544822\\
    1.9 2   0.131646861482907   0.131646861482907\\
    2   0.1 0.128455491258638   0.128455491258638\\
    2   0.2 0.128455491258638   0.128455491258638\\
    2   0.3 0.128440427480678   0.128440427480678\\
    2   0.4 0.128367342267098   0.128367342267098\\
    2   0.5 0.128298056445173   0.128298056445173\\
    2   0.6 0.128190359519678   0.128190359519678\\
    2   0.7 0.128169098158383   0.128169098158383\\
    2   0.8 0.128258788726972   0.128258788726972\\
    2   0.9 0.128348205497984   0.128348205497984\\
    2   1   0.128509084764559   0.128509084764559\\
    2   1.1 0.128719521566905   0.128719521566905\\
    2   1.2 0.128991223450223   0.128991223450223\\
    2   1.3 0.129326058440497   0.129326058440497\\
    2   1.4 0.129678854984267   0.129678854984267\\
    2   1.5 0.130057292206577   0.130057292206577\\
    2   1.6 0.13040254099493    0.13040254099493\\
    2   1.7 0.130716793578018   0.130716793578018\\
    2   1.8 0.131170075004532   0.131170075004532\\
    2   1.9 0.131711831387218   0.131711831387218\\
    2   2   0.13222817224358    0.13222817224358\\
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%

\end{document}
```

Can someone explain this strange behaviour? I also tried different printers.

Comment: which viewer you printing from and is your printer PS capable ?

Comment: They discussed a similar problem [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/261754/print-problem-with-3d-pgfplots-surf-shader-interp) and at sourceforge. Apparently, a printer driver was the cause. There are more information in the Sourceforge topic.

Comment: I use Adobe Acrobat to print the file and tried to print the Figures from PCL and PS printer. The PS printer doesn't even start printing and the PCL printer only delivers the desired output with the setting [shader=faceted interp, faceted color=black,...] which results in a PDF with high memory requirements.